# Merge rows based on index

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this,

```
Timestamp Meter1 Meter2
0         234    NaN
1         235    NaN
2         236    NaN
0         NaN    100
1         NaN    101
2         NaN    102
```

and I'm having trouble merging the rows based on the index Timestamp to something like this,

```
Timestamp Meter1 Meter2
0         234    100
1         235    101
2         236    102
```

Answer (score 3):

**Option 0**

```
df.max(level=0)

           Meter1  Meter2
Timestamp                
0           234.0   100.0
1           235.0   101.0
2           236.0   102.0
```

---

**Option 1**

```
df.sum(level=0)

           Meter1  Meter2
Timestamp                
0           234.0   100.0
1           235.0   101.0
2           236.0   102.0
```

---

**Option 2**
Disturbing Answer

```
df.stack().unstack()

           Meter1  Meter2
Timestamp                
0           234.0   100.0
1           235.0   101.0
2           236.0   102.0
```

---

As brought up by @jezrael and linked to issue [**here**](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8427)

However, As I've understood `groupby.first` and `groupby.last` is that it will return the first (or last) valid value in the group per column.  In other words, it is my belief that this is working as intended.

**Option 3**

```
df.groupby(level=0).first()

           Meter1  Meter2
Timestamp                
0           234.0   100.0
1           235.0   101.0
2           236.0   102.0
```

---

**Option 4**

```
df.groupby(level=0).last()

           Meter1  Meter2
Timestamp                
0           234.0   100.0
1           235.0   101.0
2           236.0   102.0
```

​

Comment: I'll mention it, but that is intended behavior.  That is, it is selecting the first non-null or valid value.  Using last selects the last non-null or valid value.

Comment: The fact that your answer is the only one without upvotes means that you're the upvoter. unfortunate no one returns the favour... hrrumph

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ see **Option 2**  Also, doesn't bother me (-:  I like my answers!

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby`:

```
df.groupby(level=0).max()
```

OR

```
df.groupby('Timestamp').max()
```

Output

```
           Meter1  Meter2
Timestamp                
0           234.0   100.0
1           235.0   101.0
2           236.0   102.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregate `sum`:

```
df = df.groupby(level=0).sum()
print (df)
           Meter1  Meter2
Timestamp                
0           234.0   100.0
1           235.0   101.0
2           236.0   102.0
```

And if only `ints`:

```
df = df.groupby(level=0).sum().astype(int)
print (df)
           Meter1  Meter2
Timestamp                
0             234     100
1             235     101
2             236     102
```

But maybe problem was you forget `axis=1` in [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
print (df1)
           Meter1
Timestamp        
0             234
1             235
2             236

print (df2)
           Meter2
Timestamp        
0             100
1             101
2             102

print (pd.concat([df1, df2]))
           Meter1  Meter2
Timestamp                
0           234.0     NaN
1           235.0     NaN
2           236.0     NaN
0             NaN   100.0
1             NaN   101.0
2             NaN   102.0

print (pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1))
           Meter1  Meter2
Timestamp                
0             234     100
1             235     101
2             236     102
```